# Add (domain) string in each string in another list (list of hostnames)

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

In Terraform for listener rule I need to add one domain, which is variable as string, to all values of string with hostnames.
terragrunt.hcl:

```
route53_domain = "dev.apple.com."
domain_list    = ["bi", "test", "app"]
```

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "lb_app" {
  listener_arn = data.aws_lb_listener.https.arn

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.lb_app.arn

  }

  condition {
    host_header {
      values = var.domain_list[*] + var.route53_domain
    }
  }
}
```

I tried join, concat, simple adding as "+" "," but it doesn't work, I am missing something.
So the output should be this:

```
# aws_lb_listener_rule.lb_app will be created
  + resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "lb_app" {
      + arn          = (known after apply)
      + id           = (known after apply)
      + listener_arn = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:*:listener/app/v*/*/*"
      + priority     = (known after apply)
      + tags_all     = (known after apply)

      + action {
          + order            = (known after apply)
          + target_group_arn = (known after apply)
          + type             = "forward"
        }

      + condition {
          + host_header {
              + values = [
                  + "bi.dev.apple.com",
                  + "test.dev.apple.com",
                  + "app.dev.apple.com",

                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

join, concat, adding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be other ways too, and one of the simple ways of achieving what you want is the following.

**Info:** I have used random `arns` to generate a `terraform plan` without creating other resources, kindly adapt them as per your requirements.

```
variable "route53_domain" {
  type        = string
  description = "(optional) route53 domain"
  default     = "dev.apple.com" ## removed '.' from the end as we join it using '.'
}
variable "domain_list" {
  type        = set(string)
  description = "(optional) subdomains"
  default     = ["bi", "test", "app"]
}

locals {
  fqdn_list = [
    for subdomain in var.domain_list : join(".", [subdomain, var.route53_domain])
  ]
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "lb_app" {
  ## Change me ##
  listener_arn = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:187416307283:listener/app/front-end-alb/8e4497da625e2d8a/9ab28ade35828f96"

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    ## Change me ##
    target_group_arn = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:187416307283:targetgroup/app-front-end/20cfe21448b66314"

  }

  condition {
    host_header {
      values = toset(local.fqdn_list)
    }
  }
}
```

### Terraform Plan

```bash
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated
with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_lb_listener_rule.lb_app will be created
  + resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "lb_app" {
      + arn          = (known after apply)
      + id           = (known after apply)
      + listener_arn = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:187416307283:listener/app/front-end-alb/8e4497da625e2d8a/9ab28ade35828f96"
      + priority     = (known after apply)
      + tags_all     = (known after apply)

      + action {
          + order            = (known after apply)
          + target_group_arn = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:187416307283:targetgroup/app-front-end/20cfe21448b66314"
          + type             = "forward"
        }

      + condition {
          + host_header {
              + values = [
                  + "app.dev.apple.com",
                  + "bi.dev.apple.com",
                  + "test.dev.apple.com",
                ]
            }
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi ishuar, thank you for your help! It works. I added this to a list of non understood but working commands :)